# sending json object to Django framework returns a 500 code error

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

I am sending an object using AJAX to a Django view. The data I am sending is mouse movement which is sent every 10 seconds to the server to be saved. Now, I have no problem reading my data from the client and server sides. The data gets saved in the database, but I get a 500 error message every time the function sends to the server gets executed. I tried to use fetch and got this error message:

```
POST error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

I searched about this error, and my understanding is that the problem is with the data type, but I am unsure how I can trace the problem and fix it. Could someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

here is my js function:

```
var target_id = '';
var eventsLog = {"mouse": []};

  function logMouse(event){
  target_id = event.target.id;
  currDate = new Date()
  start_time = currDate.getHours() + ':' + currDate.getMinutes() + ':' + currDate.getSeconds() + ':' + currDate.getMilliseconds();

 var insert = [start_time, target_id];
  (eventsLog.mouse).push(insert);
}
var timesPerSecond = 5; 
var wait = false;
$(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
  if (!wait) {   
      logMouse(event);
      wait = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
          wait = false;
      }, 1000 / timesPerSecond);
  } 
});
const post_url = server_url;
  function sendMovement() {
   /* fetch(post_url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(eventsLog),
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(response => {
      console.log('POST response:', response);

  }).catch(error => {
      console.log('POST error:', error);
  });*/

    $.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: server_url,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify(eventsLog),
dataType: "json",

success: function () {
  
      },
      error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' +errorThrown)
      }
});
```

and this is my Django view:

```
movement = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

and I checked the data type received in Django and it is a dictionary.

Comment: Did you try with `print(request.data)` in Django? I suggest you for testing, send your data in small pieces, to find where the problem happens. or you can use `try/except`.

Comment: I tried `print(request.POST)` right after `if request.method == 'POST'` and I got `<QueryDict: {}>` this is strange because the data gets saved in the database. Am I missing something? I also try `try/except` with `DataError` and `SuspiciousOperation` but nothing. Any exception you recommend trying?

Comment: You are missing [`X-CSRFToken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) in the request header.

Comment: thanks @Niko I tried adding the CSRF-token but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrieve csrftoken from cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) and [attach it on the request header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to send the request every ten seconds. Of course you can implement with [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but since you were using `jQuery` on your movement function, I also used it to send an AJAX.

get_mouse_movement.html
(just the script part)

```
<script>
    var target_id = '';
    var eventsLog = {"mouse": []};
    var timesPerSecond = 5; 
    var wait = false;

    function getCookie(name) {
        ...
    }

    function logMouse(event){
        target_id = event.target.id;
        currDate = new Date()
        start_time = currDate.getHours() + ':'
            + currDate.getMinutes() + ':' 
            + currDate.getSeconds() + ':' 
            + currDate.getMilliseconds();

        console.log([start_time, target_id])
        eventsLog.mouse.push([start_time, target_id]);
    };

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
        if (!wait) {   
            logMouse(event);
            wait = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                wait = false;
            }, 1000 / timesPerSecond);
        }
    });

    function sendLog() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/your/url/',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify(eventsLog),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.message);
                eventsLog.mouse = [];
            },
        });
    };

    setInterval(function(){
        sendLog();
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def mouse_movement(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'log is saved'})
    return render(request, 'get_mouse_movement.html')
```

[`.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts, str, bytes or bytearray. You do not need to decode it.